# How to create a long-format data from messy data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel file with data that I have to tidy up in excel. The file comes from invoice software, I have no control over the export options - there are no options actually but an Export Button.

The invoices are one after another having subfields of sold products and every invoice is separated by a repetition of the column names. Please, take a look at the pic for a better understanding.

[image]

What I want to achieve is a long-format data with fields: Company, Invoice, Date, Product, Quantity, and Price Per Item.

[image]

I've uploaded the sample file on [MediaFire](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pbx1fqqyqn6vn2t/messy_invoices.xlsx/file). It has two Sheets.
Sheet **Start** is how I receive the file, Sheet **End Result** is what I want to achieve.

Any idea on how to approach this issue is highly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the VBA code or the Power BI can help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I may give it a try.

Comment: Power Query (in Excel) is also an option. Especially with the fixed structure, it should be feasible with PQ with Group and custom aggregation; or using VBA and the Dictionary object.